# Remove value if it doesn't exist in another file

Tags: sql, sql-server

We receive a file every month with the following layout:

[image]

which is used to update the table below:

[image: table to be updated from file]

My task is to delete any `CValue` from the table if the corresponding `GNumber` is missing from the file, otherwise insert any new `GNumber`'s. I also have a question on the requirements, the following is taken from a conversation:

> Q:
> Can you confirm that desired behavior is to simply load the new file, provided the delta in either direction isn't too large? Is there a need to maintain a history?

> A:
> Confirmed and no need for history as we have the raw files ...

Could someone please explain the terms ***delta*** and ***history*** in this context? I doubt that they need a temporal table and this would be of greater help. Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to clarify your business requirements with the relevant stakeholders

Comment: Also do not use images, use table markdown

Comment: We can't tell you what others meant by those phrases, as we have far less context for your work than you do. Speak to whomever gave you the work and ask them to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is mentioned in comments we can't give you the true meaning of delta and history as we do not have enough context. What we can give you is general meaning of those term in context of data imports or manipulation.

Delta means difference between the two states of data or collection of data.

In this case delta could mean a separate list of `GNumber` with additional value of state that would be either `Deleted` or `Added`. If `GNumber` is missing in the file, but is in the current table that would be with value of state `Deleted`. If the `GNumber` is in the new file, but is missing in current table that would be with value of state `Added`. If there is no change there won't be delta as no change of state is present.

History means that you track each change of state that happened to any existing value/row in current table during imports.

It could be done by storing delta value with attached values from current data before the change in separate table to history of changes.

Comment: Thanks! that was cogent and helpful. I'll attempt to tackle the query from the viewpoint that you've given. Again, thanks.

Comment: No worries. Hope it helps.

Comment: @Joliet Odd that you would trust the definition provided by a complete stranger over that of an official dictionary.

Comment: @DaleK Dude, official dictionary is written by stranger. You are a stranger too(By your logic why should anyone listen to you?). Not to mention there is no official entry for delta in the context of computer science and data manipulation anywhere. The term was taken from maths which definition is "The difference between two values of a variable". There is nothing wrong with my explanation. If you feel like there is something you can add to it, leave a comment or edit the answer.  Cheers.

Comment: @dropoutcoder it wasn't a criticism of you, your definition sounds good to me. But it's a very strange thing for someone to post on here to clarify their business requirements.